# Как выводить данные из хранимой процедуры sql server в php?

Tags: php, sql-server

```
    <?php
include 'connect.php';

$sday = '1';
$eday = '1';
$t = '1';

$query = "{ call dbo.GetProduct (@StartDay = ?,@EndDate = ?,@t= ?)}";


$params = array(
                array(&$sday, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array(&$eday, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array(&$t, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
                );

$smtp = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, $params);

if(sqlsrv_execute($smtp)){
     print "success";
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($smtp, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
       print_r($row);
   
    }
  print "<br />";
  echo "ID: ".$row['id']."\n";    
  echo "Name: ".$row['name']."\n";    
  echo "categories".$row['categories']."\n";  
}else{
    print_r( sqlsrv_errors());
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($smtp);
sqlsrv_close($conn);


?>
```

**Результат выводится только success** как выводить данный из хранимой процедуры на браузер в php?

Comment: результат пустой небось. зы: `echo` команды вне цикла фетча ничего вам не выведут.

Comment: вообще по моему лучше использовать PDO. установите модуль PDO для SqlServer, куда удобнее

Comment: echo команды при вывода данных из таблиц показал результат, но из процедуры не получается

Comment: PDO модули все установлено, смотря примерны не смогла так подключить